# How to check live stream information of a youtube channel without using Search.list from youtube data api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

Basically, I want to check if several channels are streaming now **without using Search.list**.

I used Search.list from youtube data API[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), but I found this method was really costly. As the page says, ***"A call to this method has a quota cost of 100 units."*** So it's extremely easy to reach the limit every day.

I have searched for hours to find another method that can provide live stream status of a particular channel. There must be something I have missed because when I enter a channel, I can easily know whether this channel is streaming now or has any live stream plan. I thought it would be a property of the channel.

However, I didn't find any related method. When I called Channels.list(), I could find uploaded videos as a playlist in "items.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads", but there's no live stream information.

The only solution I've come up with is to request the page https://www.youtube.com/channel/channel_id/live and check if it contains "offline", but **I think it might be better to use their own API.**

Comment: How frequently are you requesting whether there are livestream events?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave It'll be requested each hour, but each time I have to request more than one times because I have to check several channels(maybe up to 50 channels?), and the daily quota is only 10, 000.

Comment: ENE Kalku, had you check if `[channel.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)` provides whether the channel is online or it retrieves livestream info?, if not, please check the documentation.

Comment: can you add in your question which `channel_id`'s are you using?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I've checked, nothing about livestream information.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=en) request for retrieve videos from channels who are currently livestreaming.

**tl;dr:** Use any livestreaming playlist available in the [YouTube Live channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig) website. Once selected the livestreaming playlist of your interest, use [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=en) for retrieve the livestreaming videos from the selected playlist.

---

You need follow these steps in order to select the livestreaming playlist and make the request using the YouTube Data API [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=en) for retrieve the livestreaming videos from the selected playlist:

1. Enter to [Live channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig) - *which according to its description*:

> Description
>
> YouTube Live - Watch great **live streams, such as live
> gaming, live music, live sports, live news**, and Google Hangouts.

2. In the main page of the "Live" channel, you'll find different kind of livestreaming events *(contained in `playlists`)* such as:

> [Live Now](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPFJz2brJ8C8IBst7O5fHgJ5): Which *in my opinion* it contains all current livestream events in YouTube *(independent of its live streaming category)*, and the live stream playlist I'll use in this demonstration.
>
> [Live Now - Gaming](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiCvVJzBupKkpGacV_ScUzA-eGF2KSZKC)
>
> [Live Now - News](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3ZQ5CpNulQnF_xhtEbWT5UFaLL2Rcevr)
>
> [Live Now - Sports](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8fVUTBmJhHK_GQ1cWZ4K8Id6qyk3IqI5)
>
> [Recent Livestreams](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPGE_-iH-I84VuLH1Qd0tX87)
>
> [Upcoming Live Streams](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPFCuw89CHvbXsoWpAnDIKBN)
>
> [Live Now - Technology](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL57quI9usf_v7KjzvWoJVxCkDgpI--HC1)
>
> [Live Now - Animals](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIFqWCuxNyogX6DDgj71LeWjycd-ZpXrW)
>
> [Mobile Live Streams](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPFy3i-iRUBt2yU0JyzgXF8P)
>
> [Recent Mobile Live Streams](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPEW_PZAWK3qYMe_PyVHJiR7)
>
> [Webcam Live Streams](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU12uITxBEPFhabx9mnl6ibNWsD6LDQN6)

3. Once selected the livestreaming playlist, use the [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=en) request for retrieve videos from the selected livestreaming playlist.

The `playlistItems.list` request for retrieve the videos from the given playlist is as follows:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2C+contentDetails&playlistId=PLU12uITxBEPFJz2brJ8C8IBst7O5fHgJ5&fields=etag%2CeventId%2Citems%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CtokenPagination%2CvisitorId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

In this case, if I execute this request in the [Google API Explorer demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252C%20contentDetails&playlistId=PLU12uITxBEPFJz2brJ8C8IBst7O5fHgJ5&fields=etag%252CeventId%252Citems%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination%252CvisitorId&_h=2&), the results will contain livestream videos from Latin America.

> N.B, the results may vary from region.

The results from the demo are:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/BZS3m3wtzWkGJhZ27amHF1uu--g\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 100,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/TQNEIYUD6c8Sx9Shf23I7LlDu28\"",
   "id": "UExVMTJ1SVR4QkVQRkp6MmJySjhDOElCc3Q3TzVmSGdKNS5BOUYwOUM3RENCNEU5MDMx",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-22T14:00:06.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "Conferencia de prensa matutina desde Palacio Nacional",
    "description": "Sigue las actividades del Presidente de México: \n\nSitio web: https://lopezobrador.org.mx/\nYouTube: https://www.youtube.com/lopezobrador\nFacebook: https://facebook.com/lopezobrador.org.mx\nTwitter: https://twitter.com/lopezobrador_\nInstagram: https://www.instagram.com/lopezobrador/\nTelegram: https://t.me/PresidenteAMLO\n\n#EnVivo #ConferenciaPresidente",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-ugBfd4HRt0/default_live.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-ugBfd4HRt0/mqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-ugBfd4HRt0/hqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-ugBfd4HRt0/sddefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-ugBfd4HRt0/maxresdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "playlistId": "PLU12uITxBEPFJz2brJ8C8IBst7O5fHgJ5",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "-ugBfd4HRt0"
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "-ugBfd4HRt0",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2019-02-21T15:28:17.000Z"
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/7O0tilY80gtiSISmtR2ST0fFfJs\"",
   "id": "UExVMTJ1SVR4QkVQRkp6MmJySjhDOElCc3Q3TzVmSGdKNS5DMDFBOTY2NDRCRkUyODk3",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-22T14:00:06.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "GH DÚO: La Casa en Directo - 24 Horas | Mediaset España",
    "description": "¿QUIERES VER LA SEÑAL DE LA CÁMARA 2? HAZ CLICK AQUÍ: https://www.mitele.es/directo/gh-duo-24h-senal-2?utm_source=youtube\n\nDescarga la app de GH DÚO para disfrutar del directo multicámara 24h, votar en las encuestas y galas semanales; y estar al tanto de todas las novedades de nuestras parejas en la casa de Guadalix: \n- Para iOS: https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/gran-hermano-vip/id616014934?mt=8\n- Para Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.mediaset.gh14&hl=es\n\nTras acoger una memorable edición VIP que ya forma parte de la historia de ‘Gran Hermano’, la casa de Guadalix de la Sierra volverá a abrir sus puertas: 16 concursantes famosos, esta vez unidos por lazos sentimentales -parejas o exparejas-, protagonizan ‘GH DÚO’, nueva versión del reality que puedes disfrutar con dos galas semanales en Telecinco. Los martes con GH DÚO: Límite 48 Horas y los jueves con la gala semanal. Recuerda, cada martes y jueves a las 22:00 tienes una cita con GH DÚO en Telecinco.\n\n¡Este año, en GH DÚO, te damos el doble!\n\nSuscríbete para tener lo mejor de Mediaset, HAZ CLICK AQUÍ: goo.gl/zNhHAN\n\nY DESCUBRE MÁS EN: https://www.mitele.es/\n\nNo olvides seguirnos en todas nuestras redes sociales:\n\nInstagram: goo.gl/ANWPMf\nFacebook: goo.gl/nHqNkV\nTwitter: goo.gl/5TqgfA\n\n#GHDÚO22F",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xFDnNOEZwDo/default_live.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xFDnNOEZwDo/mqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xFDnNOEZwDo/hqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "playlistId": "PLU12uITxBEPFJz2brJ8C8IBst7O5fHgJ5",
    "position": 1,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "xFDnNOEZwDo"
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "xFDnNOEZwDo",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2019-01-15T07:02:52.000Z"
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/LbTCIKMy5TQIN0smP0wA7dA6vsw\"",
   "id": "UExVMTJ1SVR4QkVQRkp6MmJySjhDOElCc3Q3TzVmSGdKNS5CQUM1Q0FEMjM4ODRBODE0",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-22T14:00:06.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "Peppa Pig en Español LIVE  -  Capitulos Completos ⭐️Pepa la Cerdita",
    "description": "Peppa Pig en Español LIVE  -  Capitulos Completos ⭐️Pepa la Cerdita\n► Aquí encontrarás todos tus vídeos favoritos, no olvides suscribirte: goo.gl/ooH7wv \n\nPeppa Pig En Español Capitulos Completos 2017 ★10★ Video De Peppa Pig En Español Capitulos Nuevos\n\nPeppa es una cerdita adorable que vive con sus papás y su hermanito George. Le encanta jugar y disfrazarse y se pasa el día saltando en los charcos de lodo que rodean su casa.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KeML7QM4U3U/default_live.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KeML7QM4U3U/mqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KeML7QM4U3U/hqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KeML7QM4U3U/sddefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KeML7QM4U3U/maxresdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "playlistId": "PLU12uITxBEPFJz2brJ8C8IBst7O5fHgJ5",
    "position": 2,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "KeML7QM4U3U"
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "KeML7QM4U3U",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2019-01-23T12:57:23.000Z"
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/6kuZv-N8F4RzpSkryFD-UXiF2gU\"",
   "id": "UExVMTJ1SVR4QkVQRkp6MmJySjhDOElCc3Q3TzVmSGdKNS5GRTIyMkM4OTJGNjg5OTA2",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-22T14:00:06.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "Conferencia Matutina de Lopez Obrador, Conociendo la Verdad de Guardia Nacional. 22 de feb del 2019",
    "description": "Lopez obrador respondiendo preguntas sobre la guardia nacional.\nVisitanos en:\nhttps://www.facebook.com/viralpanchito\nhttps://twitter.com/viralpancho\n\nPuedes apoyar a Viral Pancho con una donacion voluntaria aqui\nhttps://www.paypal.me/viralpancho",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NBR3AIbFdiI/default_live.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NBR3AIbFdiI/mqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NBR3AIbFdiI/hqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NBR3AIbFdiI/sddefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/NBR3AIbFdiI/maxresdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "playlistId": "PLU12uITxBEPFJz2brJ8C8IBst7O5fHgJ5",
    "position": 3,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "NBR3AIbFdiI"
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "NBR3AIbFdiI",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2019-02-22T12:46:00.000Z"
   }
  },
  {

   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/R8tPzgtvpcLUQ7234B21zC0sTVM\"",
   "id": "UExVMTJ1SVR4QkVQRkp6MmJySjhDOElCc3Q3TzVmSGdKNS5ERTI4MUI3MTBBMTdEQTZG",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-22T14:00:06.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC4R8DWoMoI7CAwX8_LjQHig",
    "title": "TN en vivo las 24hs",
    "description": "TN en vivo. Suscribite al canal líder en noticias de Argentina.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-1xif50QMr4/default_live.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-1xif50QMr4/mqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-1xif50QMr4/hqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-1xif50QMr4/sddefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-1xif50QMr4/maxresdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Live",
    "playlistId": "PLU12uITxBEPFJz2brJ8C8IBst7O5fHgJ5",
    "position": 4,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "-1xif50QMr4"
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "-1xif50QMr4",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2018-08-16T17:56:20.000Z"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```