# Check if youtube channel is livestreaming

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get the YT Data API to work and it kinda does work, but I've came across a few inconsistencies where I'm not sure if they are there for a reason.

First: I'm trying to build a discord bot which can announce streams from youtube. Therefore it needs to be able to retrieve channel ids by usernames and live stream information by the retrieved channel id. I want to use the channels endpoint and the search.list endpoint, such that it can do these things automatically (even though it's very expensive).

I'm using this request from the `search.list` endpoint `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=[channelID]=video&eventType=live&key=[myKey]` to check if it actually works. So I picked two completely random channels which were streaming at the time, took the channel id and sent the request. However I only got a response for one of the two channels. The empty response didn't feature any `items` which would contain the relevant information. I don't really know, why this is.

Comment: Please, @HimmDawg, take into account that asking multiple questions in one post goes against basic SO guidelines. Every SO user is *free* to post as many questions as he/she needs be answered.

Comment: Whoops. I'm very sorry. I asked this kind of question once already and thought I could speed up the process and ask my other questions related to this too. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll fix this.

Comment: @HimmDawg check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56510879/12511801) or the other answers in the link.