# Scrape youtube channel page to see if live streaming is live weidner/goutte package

Tags: web-scraping, youtube, laravel-8, goutte

I am trying to check if some channel live streaming is live now without youtube data api. I am using laravel 8 (weidner/goutte) package but i am unable to find  {"text":" watching"} string. can anybody help please.

Found this but cant figure out how to do it in laravel
[How to find if a youtube channel is currently live streaming without using search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385532/how-to-find-if-a-youtube-channel-is-currently-live-streaming-without-using-searc)

Tried this but it returns nothing

```
$page-\>filter('.text-wrapper style-scope ytd-video-renderer .style-scope ytd-video-renderer ytd-video-meta-block .style-scope ytd-video-meta-block .style-scope ytd-video-meta-block')-\>each(function ($node) {
dump($node-\>text());
});
```

Comment: What is the channel you're checking if is livestreaming?

Comment: yes i am checking if some channel is livestreaming