# Ping YouTube's servers to see if a channel (my own) is currently live streaming for a front end web app

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm looking to implement a feature that shows a little "Live now" div on my site. My site has no backend.

I wanted to simply ping YouTube's servers to see if I am streaming. A true or false is all I need.

I don't understand why this is so complicated to do. From what I understand, google would want me to have every user of my site sign into their own google account in order to send this ping request. Nobody is going to want to sign into their google account when they first login just so I can show a little icon on my site that says I am currently live streaming. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Are there simple free backend hosters that could accomplish this task?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454238/how-to-check-if-youtube-channel-is-streaming-live

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70026382/7123660) is a login-less, quota-less and client-side only solution.

Comment: @Gamepro5 check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56510879/12511801) or try the answers provided there.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too sure but maybe the website ifttt could handle that. I remember it having a lot of options. Have a look into that. Maybe that does the job

Link: https://ifttt.com

Have a good day!